# How can I share voice file(mpeg) which in app files to other app(like whatsapp) in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, share, sharefile

I tried flutter share 2.0.1 pluggin for share voice file but it did not work(No such file). Could you solve this problem or how can I share voice file to other app? Here is my code and error screenshot.

---

```
E/flutter (31567): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(assets/voices/pırt.mpeg (No such file or directory), null, null, null)
E/flutter (31567): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:597:7)
E/flutter (31567): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:158:18)
```

---

```
IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.send),
              color: Colors.black,
              iconSize: 35,
              onPressed: () {
                try{
                  Share.shareFiles(["assets/voices/pırt.mpeg"],text: "Share");
                }
                catch(ex){
                  print(ex);
                }
              },
            ),
```

Comment: Errors should be copy-pasted as text into your question, just like your code. Not as images.

Comment: Thank you :) do u know my problem solution ?

Comment: I'm not sure how "Thank you" is a response to my previous comment. You have to address what I said before you get answers.

Comment: "Thank you" for said my mistake. I did not know that and u teach me something :)

Comment: That usually means taking action of some kind with the new knowledge. I see you now edited in the error. That's what was expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states, `assets/voices/pırt.mpeg` is not a valid path to a file on the OS. That's an asset, packaged into your application. If you want to share assets, you need to make them a file on the device first.

You'll need to add the path_provider dependency:

```yaml
dependencies:
  path_provider: ^2.0.1
```

Then, make a new `File` and write the data from the asset to the `File`:

```dart
//Get directory and make a file object
final Directory dir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
final File file = File(dir.path + '/mpeg_data');

//Get data from assets
ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/voices/pırt.mpeg');

//Write actual data
await file.writeAsBytes(data.buffer.asUint8List());
```

This should all go before you share the file. Then when you share the file, use the path of the file object you created:

```dart
//Get directory and make a file object
final Directory dir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
final File file = File(dir.path);

//Get data from assets
ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/voices/pırt.mpeg');

//Write actual data
await file.writeAsBytes(data.buffer.asUint8List());

try{
  Share.shareFiles([file.path],text: "Share");
}
catch(ex){
  print(ex);
}
```

Comment: ```E/flutter (32083): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/data/user/0/com.example.replik/cache' (OS Error: Is a directory, errno = 21)
E/flutter (32083): #0      _File.open.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:356:9)
E/flutter (32083): #1      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)
E/flutter (32083): #2      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)```

Comment: I tried your solution. I think it is solve my problem but another problem appered.

Comment: @MuhammetKorkmaz I forgot to add a file name. See the edit.